# Why is this code using Google Charts so fragile?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to understand how to use Google Charts and have written this program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     .signal {
       border: 5px solid #333;
       border-radius: 30px;
       height: 30px;
       left: 50%;
       margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
       opacity: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       width: 30px;

       animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
       animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     }

     @keyframes pulsate {
       0% {
         transform: scale(.1);
         opacity: 0.0;
       }
       50% {
         opacity: 1;
       }
       100% {
         transform: scale(1.2);
         opacity: 0;
       }
     }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

     var extrema = [[{label:"Time", id:"time", type:"datetime"},
                     {label:"Lows", id:"lows", type:"number"},
                     {label:"Highs", id:"highs", type:"number"}]];

     var readings = [];


     function drawHighLowChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(extrema, false);
       var options = {
         title:'High/Low',
         //curveType: 'function',
         legend: { position: 'right'},
         hAxis: {format: 'MM/dd',
                 gridlines: {count: extrema.length - 1}}
       };
       var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("High_Low"));
       chart.draw(data, options);
     }




     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
         {
           var channel_data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
           var feeds = channel_data.feeds;
         }

       for (var i in feeds)
         {
           readings.push([new Date(Date.parse(feeds[i].created_at)),
                          parseFloat( feeds[i].field1).toFixed(1)]);
         }


       var low = readings[0][1];
       var high =readings[0][1];
       var current_date = readings[0][0];
       for (var i in readings)
         {
           if (readings[i][0].getDate() != current_date.getDate())
             {
               extrema.push([new Date(current_date.getFullYear(),
                                      current_date.getMonth(), current_date.getDate()),
                             low,
                             high]);
               current_date = readings[i][0];
               low = readings[i][1];
               high = readings[i][1];
             }
           else
             {
               low = Math.min(low, readings[i][1]);
               high = Math.max(high, readings[i][1]);
             }
         }
       extrema.push([current_date, low, high]);

       //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = extrema;
       drawHighLowChart();
     };

     request.open("GET", "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/227030/fields/1.json?days=5", true);
     request.send();


    </script>
  </head>


  <body>

    <h2>Corazon del Bosque Temperature Record </h2>


    <div id="Daily Temps" style="width: 900px; height: 500px">
    </div>
    <div id="High_Low" style="width: 900px; height: 500px">
      <div class="signal"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Almost anything I do will break this. For example, I tried adding

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

to the header, and the code produces an error that arrayToDataTable is not a function.
If I just delete the blank line before the commented out line

```
 //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = extrema;
```

I get an error that LineChart is not a constructor.

I've checked for hidden chars lurking in the code (using whitespace-mode in emacs) and nothing is there.

What should I be looking for to explain this behavior?
I'm testing this in the latest version of Firefox on Windows, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to make sure google charts has finished loading before trying to use the library

there are a couple ways, you can use method `setOnLoadCallback`,
or the promise that the `load` statement returns

try it like this...

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}).then(function () {  // <-- promise
   var extrema = [[{label:"Time", id:"time", type:"datetime"},
                   {label:"Lows", id:"lows", type:"number"},
                   {label:"Highs", id:"highs", type:"number"}]];

   var readings = [];


   function drawHighLowChart() {
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(extrema, false);
     var options = {
       title:'High/Low',
       //curveType: 'function',
       legend: { position: 'right'},
       hAxis: {format: 'MM/dd',
               gridlines: {count: extrema.length - 1}}
     };
     var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("High_Low"));
     chart.draw(data, options);
   }




   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
       {
         var channel_data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         var feeds = channel_data.feeds;
       }

     for (var i in feeds)
       {
         readings.push([new Date(Date.parse(feeds[i].created_at)),
                        parseFloat( feeds[i].field1).toFixed(1)]);
       }


     var low = readings[0][1];
     var high =readings[0][1];
     var current_date = readings[0][0];
     for (var i in readings)
       {
         if (readings[i][0].getDate() != current_date.getDate())
           {
             extrema.push([new Date(current_date.getFullYear(),
                                    current_date.getMonth(), current_date.getDate()),
                           low,
                           high]);
             current_date = readings[i][0];
             low = readings[i][1];
             high = readings[i][1];
           }
         else
           {
             low = Math.min(low, readings[i][1]);
             high = Math.max(high, readings[i][1]);
           }
       }
     extrema.push([current_date, low, high]);

     //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = extrema;
     drawHighLowChart();
   };

   request.open("GET", "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/227030/fields/1.json?days=5", true);
   request.send();
 });
```

Comment: That appears to work - still have a few more things to try before I'm sure. Since I'm high latency, satellite internet, it's not surprising that loading issues could be involved. What I still don't understand is how a change as simple as adding a blank line to the file will consistently break the code. If it acted non-deterministically it might make more sense, but I get consistent behavior in terms of the simplest things breaking the code.